# Is a Self Join in Kafka Streams possible?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We looking at Kafka Streams as a way to solve comparisons in flight. Specifically, we have data arriving to a Kafka topic in the order of ~15,000 transactions per second, and we would like to do comparison operations on the records as they roll by. The records are very wide (1900 columns or thereabouts), but the comparison operations occur on very few columns (~10-20). Our comparison window is about a minute.

The scenario would be something like this:

- Message 1 arrives with values of foo, bar, foobar, barfoo, 12, 34 at time 00s
- Message 2 arrives with values of foo, bat, barbat, batbar, 12, 57 at time 05s
- Message 3 arrives with values of foo, bay, barbat, baybat, 14, 19 at time 10s
- Message 4 arrives with values of foo, bar, foobar, barfoo, 12, 50 at time 15s
- Message 5 arrives with values of bar, bat, barbat, batbar, 14, 18 at time 40s
- Message 6 arrives with values of foo, bar, foobar, barfoo, 12, 36 at time 59s

We would like to be able to read the stream, identify that messages 1, 4, and 6 all match our comparison criteria, and then discard messages 1 and 6 while keeping message 4.

I found a comment from Gouzhang Wang in Nov 2016 suggesting implementing this through the Processor API.  Is this still the current best approach?

Comment: Ideally, we would like to solve this with a sliding time window

Comment: It should be possible to do this with a sliding time windowed stream-stream join. Note, that it would be less resource efficient that using Processor API.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax can you elaborate on your comment ?

Comment: A self-join actually only needs a single state-store. However, if you use a stream-stream-join (ie, `KStream stream = builder.stream(...); KStream joinedStream = stream.join(stream)`) you get two state store because the operator thinks it is joining two different input streams. (cf https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7497) -- Thus, you could implement a self-join manually via `stream.transform()` and use as single state store.